# mySQL with PHP to JSON for clientside chart

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, highcharts

I am hoping to get a better way to do what I am doing.  I have several charts to do and want to go about it the best way.

I am using HighCharts which requires a JSON object for data.  I am using Laravel as my back end.  I am sending 2 variables (1 for labels & 1 for values) to my view.  I see i can do this in the controller but haven't started yet

My Issue:

I have this table

```
|     date    | printer  | quant  |
| 2017-01-23  | JP1      |  20    |
| 2017-01-23  | JP1      |  12    |
| 2017-01-23  | JP2      |  18    |
| 2017-01-24  | JP5      |  16    |
| 2017-01-24  | JP1      |   8    |
| 2017-01-26  | JP2      |   12   |
```

I think that hits all the cases, variable printers, missed days, need to sum quantity per day and make 0 if missing.  Need an array for each printer which I dont have a premade list because they change a lot.  my querys will be with a date range.  The list of printers will be distinct for that date range.

What I have done is make a pivot mySQL query which gets me this

```
[
{
"date": "2017-01-23",
"sum": "1416",
"JP4_3": "375",
"JP4_1": "533",
"JP4_2": "508",
"B3": null,
"A2": null
},
{
"date": "2017-01-24",
"sum": "2151",
"JP4_3": "847",
"JP4_1": "499",
"JP4_2": "805",
"B3": null,
"A2": null
},
{
"date": "2017-01-25",
"sum": "2097",
"JP4_3": "284",
"JP4_1": "917",
"JP4_2": "896",
"B3": null,
"A2": null
}
]
```

I can loop through and grab each property to make an array.

I am wondering is there a better way.  I need to get a label and data to work with high charts.  Here is an example.

```
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
    }]
```

I know this is a complicated and long winded question.  Thank you for any help and direction.

Comment: There's probably not going to be a better for formatting your data than looping and making your own array since highcharts needs such a specific format. I'm saying this after having integrated highcharts into a few different PHP/MySQL projects, a couple having been Laravel. Generally I loop through then cache the chart data (either in memory or in a table) to save processing large datasets frequently.

Comment: Hi @Samsquanch.  could you provide an example of that.  Something simple.  I am coming from c# and been a long time since I touched php.  There are several functions that I think are helpful here that I dont know to look for.

Comment: Or if you know a good resource for this senario.  I found one but they dont show the database so its not as clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return just array of data from laravel and in view balde use

```
var data = JSON.parse( '{!! json_encode($chartData) !!}' );
```

I used this in my code

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to give a code example for how I did this.  Kind of a pain but from Samsquanch i guess this is normal.  This does several database calls but still plenty fast for me.  This is using laravel framework.

```
    // Main chart info
    $PrinterChartArray ["chart"] = array (
            'type' => 'line' 
    );
    $PrinterChartArray ["title"] = array (
            "text" => "Units per Printer" 
    );
    $PrinterChartArray ["credits"] = array (
            "enabled" => false 
    );
    $PrinterChartArray ["xAxis"] = array (
            "categories" => array () 
    );
    $PrinterChartArray ["tooltip"] = array (
            "valueSuffix" => " units" 
    );
    $PrinterChartArray ["yAxis"] = array (
            "title" => array (
                    "text" => "Units" 
            ) 
    );

    // Get series Names
    $printerNames = PrintJob::distinct()->select('printer')
        ->whereDate('job_date', '>=', date($from))
        ->whereDate('job_date', '<=', date($to))
        ->get();

    // loop through series names and set series name and data for high charts
    $chartSeries = [];
    foreach($printerNames as $printer)
    {
        $printName = $printer->printer;

        // Used where inside join so wouldnt miss dates
        // used a calendar table with all dates to fill in missing dates
        $data = PrintJob::select(DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(print_jobs.quantity), 0) as sum'), DB::raw('calendar.datefield'))
        ->rightJoin('calendar', function($join) use ($printName)
        {
            $join->on('print_jobs.job_date', '=', 'calendar.datefield')
                ->where('printer', '=', $printName);
        })
        ->whereDate('calendar.datefield', '>=', date($from))
        ->whereDate('calendar.datefield', '<=', date($to))         
        ->groupBy('calendar.datefield')
        ->orderBy('calendar.datefield', 'ASC')
        //->toSql();
        ->get();
        //->pluck('sum');

        // Needed to convert the returned value from a string value to a int value (apparently a driver issue with php and mysql)
        foreach ($data as $key => $var) {
            $data[$key] = (int)$var->sum;
        }
        // Add series to high chart
        $chartSeries[] = array(
            "name" => $printName,
            "data" => $data
        );
    }

    // Unessesary to use PrintJob for this but keeping similar to series to not mess up label
    $chartLabel = PrintJob::select(DB::raw('calendar.datefield'))
        ->rightJoin('calendar', function($join) use ($printName)
        {
            $join->on('print_jobs.job_date', '=', 'calendar.datefield');
        })
        ->whereDate('calendar.datefield', '>=', date($from))
        ->whereDate('calendar.datefield', '<=', date($to))         
        ->groupBy('calendar.datefield')
        ->orderBy('calendar.datefield', 'ASC')
        //->toSql(); --- This will show the actual query
        //->get(); --- Will give array of objects
        ->pluck('calendar.datefield'); // --- Will give a array of just the values wanted

    $PrinterChartArray ["series"] = $chartSeries;
    $PrinterChartArray ["xAxis"] = array (
            "categories" => $chartLabel 
    );
    //return $PrinterChartArray; -- used to see output without view

  return view('print.charts', compact('jobsByDayLabels', 'jobsByDayValues', 'unitsByDayLabels', 'unitsByDayValues', 'PrinterChartArray'));
```

And this is the view part

```
    <!-- Chart for Units by Printer by Day -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="x_panel">
            <div id="printerUnitsByDay" style="min-width: 310px; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this below is the script on the view

```
$(function() {
  $('#printerUnitsByDay').highcharts({!! json_encode($PrinterChartArray) !!})
});
```